# Check if string is equal to a double

Tags: c#

```
String[] vals = s.Split(';');
String o = "X=" + vals[0] + "  Y=" + vals[1] + "  Z=" + vals[2];
```

I have this code to display the values of x,y,z. Now I want to implement if the x,y,z values = 225.0 . something would happen.

I can't just

```
double num = 225.0;
if (vals[0] = num );
```

It says, I cannot convert 'double' to 'string' . How should I do this ?

Comment: you can try vals[0].equals(num);

Comment: `string num = "225.0";`?

Comment: `if (vals[0] == "225.0" )`?

Comment: Use Convert.ToDouble method to convert string to double data type

Comment: 1. In your if statement use '==' instead of '='
2. You need to convert vals[0] from string to double using  Double.Parse(vals[0])

So those two lines would look like this:
`double num = 225.0;`
`if (Double.Parse(vals[0])==num) { /*your code here*/ }`

@Slaven Tojić I know instead of going to the next line i posted it as a comment :)

Comment: Thanks SeM, it worked. :) Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: @eren sorry I only saw the first part of your comment

Comment: No problem, was my bad i should know that hitting enter will post the comment :)

Comment: @YannKang The problem is, that we do not have much context, what are you trying to achieve? The solutions I've commented, is only to show how basic string comparison works, but in real project it is unlikely to happen - to compare with static string or declare number as string.

Comment: @SeM, in this case, I just want to check if x,y,z values =225.0, it displays a text. Thats about it.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert `vals[0]` to double with `ConvertToDouble`:

```
double num = 225.0;
if (Convert.ToDouble(vals[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == num)
```

If you want to check if all values in `vals` are equale to `225.0` you could use LINQ `All`:

```
if (vals.All(x => Convert.ToDouble(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == num))
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0trf7s)**

Answer (score 0):

Your question has more complexity than it seems. At first glance, the answer to the question "how do I compare a string with a floating point number" is "convert the string to a floating point number and then compare the numbers":

```
double num = 225.0;
if ( Convert.ToDouble(vals[0]) == num ) {
    // Do something
}
```

This however can cause subtle bugs that you *might* catch with some extensive testing, but that you might also miss. The reason is that floating point data types have a precision and comparisons for direct equality can yield `false` due to rounding errors, even when you expect the result to be `true`. A detailed description of the problem and how you overcome it can be found [on this site](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

In your case you should consider a simpler solution that will work in many cases in practice: Compare fixed point numbers. In the .NET framework this means comparing variables of type `decimal`:

```
decimal num = 225M;
if ( Convert.ToDecimal(vals[0]) == num ) {
    // Do something
}
```

There is still a problem in this code though, since the conversion is done based on the local culture of the host system. Usually, you want to compare based on a fixed culture:

```
decimal num = 225M;
if ( Convert.ToDecimal(vals[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == num ) {
    // Do something
}
```

If comparing with decimals doesn't work for you due to the nature of your data, you should consider a more complex floating point comparison as described in the linked article.